# Multiple simultaneous patterns for grep

Tags: bash, grep

I need to see if user exists in `/etc/passwd`. I'm using grep, but I'm having a hard time passing multiple patterns to grep.

I tried

```
if [[ ! $( cat /etc/passwd | egrep "$name&/home" ) ]];then
   #user doesn't exist, do something
fi
```

I used ampersand instead of | because both conditions must be true, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ getent passwd foo bar base
```

Finally :

```
if getent &>/dev/null passwd user_X; then
    do_something...
else
    do_something_else...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, choose the `getent` for elegancy :)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your assumptions, regex does not recognize `&` for intersection, even though it would be a logical extension.

To locate lines which match multiple patterns, try

```
grep -e 'pattern1.*pattern2' -e 'pattern2.*pattern1' file
```

to match the patterns in any order, or switch to e.g. Awk:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file
```

(though in your specific example, just `"$name.*/home"` ought to suffice because the matches must always occur in this order).

As an aside, your contorted `if` condition can be refactored to just

```
if grep -q pattern file; then ...
```

The `if` conditional takes as its argument a command, runs it, and examines its exit code. Any properly written Unix command is written to this specification, and returns zero on success, a nonzero exit code otherwise. (Notice also the absence of a useless `cat` -- almost all commands accept a file name argument, and those which don't can be handled with redirection.)